# How to match census tracts from different years

Tags: geocoding, census

I am trying to compare data from census tracts over time, but some census tracts change from census to census. Is there a way to match up old census tract IDs with what the new census tract ID is? Specifically for 1990 and 2010 censuses.

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is several months old, but in case you still are wondering about this, (or for anyone who stumbles on here later) - the IPUMS project has geographic crosswalk files available on their website for 1990 blocks to 2010 blocks. 
Those are available here:
https://www.nhgis.org/user-resources/geographic-crosswalks

Keep in mind that if you are doing spatial analysis the Census Bureau did some clean up of their geography, improving the accuracy of the boundary lines around 2008 and after so you may find some discrepancies if you're doing spatial overlays. See here for more info:
https://www.nhgis.org/documentation/gis-data